# How to get the value of checkbox in gridview using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, checkbox

I want to get the value of a `CheckBox` in a `GridView`. I'm able to bind the `GridView` using the event `RowDataBound`. But on a `Click` event of a `Button` the value of the `CheckBox` is always false even if I checked the `CheckBox`.

Code Behind:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDatabound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList dddate = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DdlDate");
            DropDownList ddYear = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DdlYear");
            for (int i = System.DateTime.Now.Year; i > (System.DateTime.Now.Year) - 100; i--)
                ddYear.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(i));
            for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++)
                dddate.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(i)); 
        }
    }
    protected void btnRetrieveCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSel");
            if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
            {

                DropDownList dddate = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DdlDate");              //Bind data to the GridView control.
                DropDownList ddYear = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DdlYear");
                DropDownList ddmonth = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DdlMonth");

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: is your `chkSel` dynamically created or design time?

Answer (score 0):

You should hook up to the Checked event on the checkbox instead of the click event.

Your question is not very clear. Can you post some more of the code. For example, what is btnRetrieveCheck - is it the actual checkbox? Please update the question with your XAML so we can see what binding is in place.

Comment: i have a gridview with several columns and a templatefield containing a checkbox. when the user clicks the checkbox i want to update the database with a 1 (if checked) or a 0 (if unchecked). thats why i'm using btnRetrieveCheck

Comment: Can you update your question to include the xaml for the DataGrid. I still don't understand. Also my comment re EndEdit applies to WinForms so I will remove it.